# Embedded IE7 browser tooltip problems

Tags: internet-explorer-7, tooltip, jsfiddle

Okay, so I have this problem and I cannot figure it out. I've looked at numerous solutions but none have worked.
I am working with a piece of software that has an embedded browser - as far as I can tell, its IE7.

I link the embedded browser to an HTML file.In the file I generate HTML via JavaScript based on values passed to the browser control via the software.

The HTML I am building is a graph.

I have a container div that holds everything.
Within it I have a div floated left that holds the scale for the graph.
I then have a div called graph which will display the data. This div is x-scrollable and has left margin so that it doesn't overlap the scale div.
Via JavaScript I build HTML code and then set the graph div's innerHTML to the new code.

The code I build consists of a column div.
Within the column div are 6 other divs positioned absolute and given a top to show them vertically aligned with the scale and based on the values passed to the control.

The number of columns depends on the number of values sent and will change.

All of this works fine and the positioned divs show up within the column where I want them.

The problem is that I want each positioned div to have a tooltip that displays the actual value.
In the browser control I must work with, these tooltips always appear behind the positioned divs in the next column and I need them to appear on top of everything.

In the example below, the tooltip appears above the data in the columns to the right.
However, in the embedded IE7 browser the data in the columns to the right appears above the tooltip.

```
    <style>
    .container
    {
        width: 800px;
        height: 600px;
        background-color: #dfd;
        overflow-x: scroll;
    }
    .scale
    {
        width: 100px;
        height: 520px;
        background-color: #fdd;
        float: left;
    }
    .graph
    {
        width: 1000px;
        height: 520px;
        background-color: #ddf;
    }
    .column
    {
        width: 20px;
        height: 520px;
        float: left;
        background-color: #fdf;
    }
    .value1
    {
        position: absolute;
        width: 24px;
    }
    .value2
    {
        position: absolute;
        width: 24px;
    }
    .value3
    {
        position: absolute;
        width: 24px;
    }
    .tooltip span
    {
        display: none;
        width: 100px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .tooltip:hover span
    {
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 24px;
        z-index: 2;
    }

</style>

<body>
    <div class="scale">Blah blah</div>
    <div class="container">

    <div class="graph">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="value1" style="top: 100px;"><a class="tooltip" href="#">1a<span>tooltip data</span></a></div>
            <div class="value2" style="top: 150px;">2a</div>
            <div class="value3" style="top: 200px;">3a</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="value1" style="top: 130px;">1b</div>
            <div class="value2" style="top: 160px;">2b</div>
            <div class="value3" style="top: 180px;">3b</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="value1" style="top: 90px;">1c</div>
            <div class="value2" style="top: 110px;">2c</div>
            <div class="value3" style="top: 140px;">3c</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pra1y0gr/) simple example.

I have tried changing position: absolute and :relative on various elements. I have tried setting z-indexes of various elements and the result is always the same. The tooltips appear behind the positioned values in columns to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

The problem was that each column div I created reset the stacking order and therefore came after - above - the column before it. The children of the previous column (including the tooltips) would appear below the new column(s).

The solution was to set the z-index for each column in the JavaScript as I created it. I set it to (99999 - theLoopIndex) so that each subsequent column had a z-index of one less than the previous column.
This meant that the children of the previous column would appear above - have a higher z-index - than the subsequent columns and their children.